# How can I add a definition to TypeScript

Tags: typescript, gulp

I have a TypeScript project which takes advantage of [`Object.groupBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/groupBy). Sadly, my TypeScript compiler doesn't know that what means.

```js
Object.groupBy(collection, ({ foo }) => foo);
// ts(2339) Property 'groupBy' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'
```

Since I'm naive and full of dreams, I figured that I could simply create my own definition file to sort that out.

```js
// lib/lib.object-groupby.d.ts
export {}

declare global {

    interface ObjectConstructor {

        /**
         * Groups the given objects by a key taken from the object values.
         * @param items Items to group.
         * @param callbackFn Function identifying the key for the groups.
         */
        groupBy<T, K extends PropertyKey>(
            items: T[],
            callbackFn: (element: T, index: number) => K
        ): Record<K, T[]>;

    }

}
```

My problem is that I can't work out how to add it to `tsconfig.json`. Whenever I try to add it so that I can compile the project using gulp-typescript, I keep seeing the same error.

I tried adding it to the `files` property, but that didn't seem to work.

```json
{
    "files": ["./assets/lib/lib.object-groupby.d.ts"]
}
```

I tried adding it to `typeRoots`, with no success again.

```json
{
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./assets/lib/lib.object-groupby.d.ts"]
}
```

How do I add the file so that my project will compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to add the solution that I ended up going with that works with Gulp and VSCode. Hopefully this will help someone else in the same frustrating situation.

For starters, here's a simplified view of my folder structure.

```
app/
├── assets/
│   ├── ts/
│   │   ├── lib/
│   │   │   └── lib.object-groupby.d.ts
│   │   ├── index.ts
│   │   ├── index.d.ts
```

The `lib.object-groupby.d.ts` file had the definition itself. Just including this file seems to be enough for VSCode to be happy.

```js
// assets/ts/lib/lib.object.groupby.d.ts
export {}

declare global {

    interface ObjectConstructor {

        /**
         * Groups the given objects by a key taken from the object values.
         * @param items Items to group.
         * @param callbackFn Function identifying the key for the groups.
         */
        groupBy<T, K extends PropertyKey>(
            items: T[],
            callbackFn: (element: T, index: number) => K
        ): Record<K, T[]>;

    }

}
```

I needed to create an `index.d.ts` file in the root that imports that definition. This allows gulp-typescript to understand and include the file.

```js
// assets/ts/index.d.ts
import "./lib/lib.object-groupby";
```

The `tsconfig.json` file didn't need anything special to be added, everything just kinda worked.